# How to change text of a button without creating object in android

Tags: android

I have tried to do like this,

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setText("HI");
```

But it is not working.
is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

```
((Button) findViewByid(R.id.button1)).setText("Hi");
```

Not sure what you are trying to realize though!

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setText("HI");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
btn.setText("HI");
```

Answer (score 0):

have to create a button object. if you want to change the name in another class, define the button object global

```
      import android.widget.Button;

      Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      button.setText("text change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
((Button) findViewByid(R.id.button1)).setText("Hi");
```

If you are trying to instantiate button inside subclass like adapters or dialogs etc , use the respective view before findViewByid.

```
((Button) view.findViewByid(R.id.button1)).setText("Hi");
```

or

```
((Button) dialog.findViewByid(R.id.button1)).setText("Hi");
```